# Wordpress Older posts & newer posts from current caterory?

Tags: wordpress, post

How can i display **5 older posts** and **5 newer posts** from current category (exclude current post). Order by post time.

Example:

---

**>> Current posts (Post on 02/11/2012 - 7:10 AM)**

---

### 5 Newest Posts

- To day news to reading 3 (12/11/2012 - 8:10 PM)
- To day news to reading 2 (12/11/2012 - 6:07 AM)
- To day news to reading 1 (12/11/2012 - 6:05 AM)
- Yesterday news to reading 2 (11/11/2012 - 9:10 PM)
- Yesterday news to reading 1 (11/11/2012 - 7:12 AM)

### **5 Newer Posts**

- Newer post to reading 5 (04/11/2012 - 8:20 PM)
- Newer post to reading 4 (03/11/2012 - 7:12 PM)
- Newer post to reading 3 (03/11/2012 - 6:10 AM)
- Newer post to reading 2 (**02/11/2012 - 8:10 AM**)
- Newer post to reading 1 (**02/11/2012 - 7:30 AM**)

### **5 Older Posts**

- Older post to reading 5 (**02/11/2012 - 6:20 AM**)
- Older post to reading 4 (**02/11/2012 - 6:12 AM**)
- Older post to reading 3 (01/11/2012 - 6:50 PM)
- Older post to reading 2 (01/11/2012 - 5:10 AM)
- Older post to reading 1 (31/10/2012 - 7:30 AM)

Answer (score 0):

Use query_posts and extract posts according to the current date distance may this link ([query_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)) will help you.